# Can you get the component encapsulation host ID?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to get the encapsulation host id that is given to a component?

If you have a component that is using `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` the element in the **DOM** will have an attribute name of something like `_nghost-par-2.` Which, is a **unique ID** given to the component to encapsulate the associated styles.

How do you get that ID as part of the component's constructor?

**Something to the effect of:**

```
@Component({
  hostId:string;
  ...
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(host:Host) {
    this.hostId = host.id;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ID consists of the following parts:

```
_nghost   -   par    -     2
   |           |           |
 static      APP_ID   _nextCompTypeId
```

**[APP_ID](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_ID-let.html)** is a just token from @angular/core

> If you need to avoid randomly generated value to be used as an
>   application id, you can provide a custom value via a DI provider
>   configuring the root Injector using this token

**_nextCompTypeId** is generated inside framework within private class `ViewUtils`.

Seems there is no a public method which can return it value. So probably the following will work

```
export class MyComponent { 
  id: string;
  constructor(@Inject(APP_ID) appId: string, vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.id = `${appId}-${vcRef.injector['_view'].viewUtils._nextCompTypeId - 1}`;
  }
}
```

Another way is get it from `attributes` via `elementRef`

### Update

If you're on **Angular 9** then follow this answer [How to access components unique encapsulation ID in Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114682/how-to-access-components-unique-encapsulation-id-in-angular-9#answer-60123609)

Comment: First time I'm see a string being build that way. That's different.

Also, if anyone else is looking at this, don't forget to add APP_ID, and Inject to your @angular/core import.

Comment: One more thing, '_nghost' is the static portion of the root component. '_ngcontent' is for each sub component. Read more here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html