# Angular and localStorage how to get an unique key per

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have a couple of reusable components that have certain filters.
I want these filters to be saved to localstorage. However since these components are reüsable i need some kind of unique id for each component because otherwise the filterkeys would all be the same for each component.

For example I have organizations and domains with 1:m relation (1 organization, many domains).
I then have a domain-table component, listing a couple domains:
(all samples below are excerpts)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-domain-table',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  styleUrls: ['component.scss']
})
export class DomainTableComponent implements OnInit {

  // filter:
  @Input()
  organizationId: string;
  
}
```

I then reüse this component on 2 pages, the domain page and the organization page:

```html
<div class="head d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-2 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom fix-width">
  <div class="head-start">
    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
    <h1 class="h2">Domains</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<app-domain-table></app-domain-table>
```

```html
<div class="head d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-2 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom fix-width">
  <div class="head-start">
    <i class="fa fa-orgs"></i>
    <h1 class="h2">Organizations</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<app-organization-table></app-organization-table>

<app-domain-table></app-domain-table>
```

No when i want to filter domains for specific organizations i simply set the `organizationId` and the component will handle the rest. I've set it up to remember this value between pages like so:

```js
  private _organizationId: number = (+localStorage.getItem('DomainTableComponent._organizationId')) ?? 0;

  public get organizationId(): number {
    return this._organizationId;
  }
  public set organizationId(value: number) {
    localStorage.setItem('DomainTableComponent._organizationId', value ? value.toString() : (0).toString());
    this._organizationId = value;
  }
```

This however causes the filter on `DomainTableComponent` to be the same for both pages. This is because they use the same key: `DomainTableComponent._organizationId`. I need to identify the component instance uniquely in some way, so i can make a key like: `DomainTableComponent._organizationId.InstaceOnDomainPage`.

**Edit:** This question poses a good solution: [How to access components unique encapsulation ID in Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114682/how-to-access-components-unique-encapsulation-id-in-angular-9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor name of the component to uniquely identify the components:

```
this.constructor.name
```

And can make unique keys using it.

Comment: And minification won't break this? Just checking

Comment: It seems like this gives the name of the component, but it seems that it will give the same for instances of the same component

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique id angular add to every element if you are using encapsulation mode (which is the default).
to get it use this inside the component class:

```
this.constructor['ɵcmp'].id
```

Comment: On Angular `^11.2.6"` this give me 'undefined' `ngOnInit(): void { console.log(this.constructor['ɵcmp']); }`